# `kubectl` fails when called from bash function

Tags: bash, environment-variables, kubectl

I'm using env-vars like `$foo` in my K8s `.yaml` files:

```
> cat .env
NAMESPACE=fred

> cat my.yaml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: $NAMESPACE
```

I throw them through `kubectl` thus:

```
function f() { ( set -a;  source .env;  cat $1 | envsubst | kubectl apply -f - ) }
f my.yaml
```

It gives:

> error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)

However,

```
> cat pure.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: fred

> kubectl apply -f pure.yaml
```

... completes fine!

What could possibly be going wrong?

Comment: Your function usage (```set -a; source .env```) suggests that you are not running this from your normal user. Am I right? If so you might have to indicate how/where your credentials are

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen No, I'm running this from the normal user. And it is finding the credentials when I run it directly without substitutions.

Comment: Ok, Can you test without the ```set -a;  source .env;``` in the function? It looks like it removed a part of your environment settings instead of adding to it.
Also add a `#!/bin/bash` to your script (if not yet present) to inform the shell that you want to use bash again

Comment: `set -a;  source .env;` is quite clear and shouldn't be a problem here, it simply takes care that `NAMESPACE=fred` is exported and it looks like this part works correct. How do you exactly call this script ? What happens if you call `kubectl apply -f pure.yaml` but also from within a bash script ? I guess problem isn't really related with a variable substitution here as it seems to work well. It's rather about invoking `kubectl commands` from your script.